# AWS Elastic Beanstalk https not working with hostinger domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have deployed my .NET Core Web API application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk , then I purchased a domain from hostinger to get a free SSL certification from Amazon ACM .
After I validated the ownership of the domain by DNS , the SSL certification was issued by ACM , after that I headed to my environment , and edited in configuration section Load Balancers .
I added a Listener with Port 443 and HTTPS protocol , then chose the certificate and the SSL policy TLS-1-2-2017...
then saved the changes .
The configuration was successfully carried , but when I access my Elastic Beanstalk url with https it gives certificate not valid like that in the picture below :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7alR.png)

can someone please guide , I have been stuck for 2 days and didn't find a solution .

Comment: Can you please [edit] to pose a clear, precise question? Maybe your question can be inferred, but this whole site is based on a framework of Q&A, so for the health of the framework, please ask a question. You can see [ask] for guidance. Note: ['Can somebody help me?' is not really a question by our community's standards](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541)